# placeholder text in dynamic prototype UITableView

Tags: uitableview

Basically, I have a UITableView which will hold, say, alarms.

There is a '+' button at the bottom of the screen to add alarms but, of course, before any alarms are added the table is blank.

If there are no alarms, and the table view is empty, I'd like there to be some sort of placeholder text like "press the + to add an alarm".

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600948/keeping-a-placeholder-cell-in-a-uitableview) and also found a suggestion about making a placeholder UITableView with a cell that shows the above text.  Then you show/hide the placeholder UITableView or the alarm UITableView depending on whether or not there are any alarms.  I couldn't get that to work and think it's a bit much for wanting a simple string to show up.

I also tried creating a placeholder UITableViewCell if there are no alarms but that messes with numberOfRowsInSection which, in turn, breaks the ability to delete cells, as well it should (because numberOfRowsInSection can never be zero).

UPDATE: I also tried adding a UILabel to the tableView's tableHeaderView (and tableFooterView).  No luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm going to give it whirl in the morning, with a rested brain, but I thought it might be helpful to post the question..

Comment: Just add `UILabel` as subview to your `UItableView`. Or you can add a custom `UIView` if you want more look.

Comment: Just do a `[self.view addSubview:myLabel]`?  What about the underlying UITableView?  Also, the controller is a TableView controller.  I wonder if that says anything about it's view..

Comment: I mean adding subview to ur tableview itself...not on the view...

Comment: Hmm.  I've tried that and had no luck.  Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040125/adding-uisearchbar-into-tableview-header-as-subview/12434826#12434826) is why - check out the first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researching on this site, I solved it by implementing the following delegate callbacks:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.alarmList.count == 0) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.text = @"press the + to add an alarm";
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.numberOfLines = 2;
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        return label;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.alarmList.count == 0) {
        return 68;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```